# Hierarchical iPhone Settings File problem -- Can't add to Settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, settings.bundle

I'm trying to add an additional iPhone Settings File type to my Settings.Bundle and reference it in my Root.plist as a Child Pane type, but it isn't working. I've followed the documentation from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html), but it will not keep the plist file as an "iPhone Settings" type. I'm assuming that is why I can't drag it to my Settings.Bundle file either.

Basically, add a new plist by selecting File > Add New File...; select Resources under iOS, and then select plist type.

Now add some plist properties to the file.

Now right-click and choose "Property List Type" and select "iPhone Settings." You'll notice the keys in the file change. That's good. Save.

Now, click on another file to view that file and click back to the new settings file. Did it change back to the old property names and property type? It does for me, so it's staying as an iPhone Settings file type, and thus isn't working.

Anyone else have this problem? I'm wondering if it is an Xcode thing, or if it's a project preference/option/setting that I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still doesn't save the settings type, but I got it working by copying the plist file into bundle from the command line.  You can also right-click the "Settings.bundle" file and select "Show Package Contents" and copy the file in Finder.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but even after putting it in the settings.bundle it changes back. Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing that caused me to waste some time: kill the settings app after making changes.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Everything else seems to update fine without killing the app but the child pane requires killing the settings app!